# MarkLogic SPARQL aggregation (COUNT) errors out

Tags: sparql, marklogic

Aggregation SPARQL queries with MarkLogic return errors for me. For example this one taken from latest MarkLogic docs:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?object (COUNT(?subject) AS ?count)
WHERE {
  ?subject <w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type/>; ?object
}
ORDER BY DESC (?count)
LIMIT 10
```

That returns

> SEM-SYNTAXERROR (err:FOER0000):
>   XDMP-UNEXPECTED err:XPST0003 1.0-ml Unexpected token XDMP-UNEXPECTED:
>   (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, function name unknown:
>   "COUNT"false syntax error, function name unknown:
>   "COUNT"18sem:sparql("SELECT (COUNT( ?PCD_01_Message ) as ?cnt) WHERE {
>   ?PCD_01_Messag...", ()

This is a fragment from a REST call response.
The developer guides mention nothing needed to include or declare in order to use the aggregation. The simple select queries work.

Any idea what is missing?

Comment: You need to post the code that generates the error.

Comment: **"Unexpected token syntax error, function name unknown: "COUNT""** sounds like there might be a syntax error,.  What's the actual query?

Comment: I get this error from any count query - to simplify the case, just copied the query from the the MarkLogic docs                                                     


SELECT DISTINCT ?object (COUNT(?subject) AS ?count)
WHERE {
?subject <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type/> ?object
}
ORDER BY DESC (?count)
LIMIT 10

Comment: same error when running from Query Console:

[1.0-ml] XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, function name unknown: "COUNT"

So - is some module not enabled/loaded/configured?

Answer (score 3):

What version of MarkLogic are you running? SPARQL 1.1 aggregates were not introduced until MarkLogic 8.

Comment: right, that explains, The version I read out at admin console is 7.0-4.1
Thanks!